# ElementTree and unicode

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, elementtree

I have this char in an xml file:

```
<data>
  <products>
      <color>fumè</color>
  </product>
</data>
```

I try to generate an instance of ElementTree with the following code:

```
string_data = open('file.xml')
x = ElementTree.fromstring(unicode(string_data.encode('utf-8')))
```

and I get the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe8' in position 185: ordinal not in range(128)
```

*(NOTE: The position is not exact, I sampled the xml from a larger one).*

How to solve it? Thanks

Comment: On a sidenote - your sample data is incorrect - *products* and *product*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You do *not* need to decode XML for ElementTree to work. XML carries it's own encoding information (defaulting to UTF-8) and ElementTree does the work for you, outputting unicode:

```
>>> data = '''\
... <data>
...   <products>
...       <color>fumè</color>
...   </products>
... </data>
... '''
>>> x = ElementTree.fromstring(data)
>>> x[0][0].text
u'fum\xe8'
```

If your data is contained in a file(like) object, just pass the filename or file object directly to the `ElementTree.parse()` function:

```
x = ElementTree.parse('file.xml')
```

Comment: Sadly there are times when we have XML that does not have embedded encoding information and Elementree is getting it wrong, returning strs with broken characters in.

Comment: @Kylotan: then those XML documents are at fault. The XML specification is *very clear* about this; the document is encoded as UTF8 unless specifically stated otherwise in the XML header.

Comment: @Kylotan: you *can* override the XML declaration with an [`ElementTree.XMLParser()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.XMLParser) object passed in to the `ElementTree.parse()` function, use that for broken XML input.

Comment: @Kylotan: that doesn't make my answer incorrect just because you have broken XML, however.

Comment: Well, it's hard for me to know if there's anything wrong with the XML given that it seemed to render ok elsewhere but I have had problems with the output, that's all I know. (Would undo the downvote, but SO doesn't allow me to.)

Comment: @Kylotan: make sure you didn't make any errors with the Unicode output when extracting data from the XML file either; Unicode can be tricky and are not precise about encodings.

Comment: @MartijnPieters FWIW I've just hit this in Python 2.6 on Windows. Have to pass a string into a function which then uses `fromstring`. Source is a UTF8 file read using `codecs.open()`. The solution does seem to be to force a conversion to utf8 in such situations.

Comment: @CharlieClark: `codecs.open()` produces a *Unicode* value, so `<type 'unicode'>`, not a byte string. Yes, you'd have to encode back to UTF-8.

Comment: I'm only experiencing problems with `xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring()` in Python 2.6 on Windows. Other platforms (Mac, Linux) don't seem to need to conversion back to an encoded string. For future reference just in case anyone else comes across the same issue.

Answer (score 35):

Might you have stumbled upon this problem while using [Requests (HTTP for Humans)](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html), `response.text` decodes the response by default, you can use `response.content` to get the undecoded data, so ElementTree can decode it itself. Just remember to use the correct encoding.

More info: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-content

Comment: In general, you should pass xml data (as bytes) directly to an XML parser unless `response.text` takes into account that `response.content` is XML and follows the corresponding standards e.g., reads the xml declaration fi any to find out the character encoding (it seems unlikely that `requests` would do that and it shouldn't).

Answer (score 15):

You need to **decode** utf-8 strings into a unicode object. So

```
string_data.encode('utf-8')
```

should be

```
string_data.decode('utf-8')
```

assuming `string_data` is actually an utf-8 string.

So to summarize: To get an utf-8 string from a unicode object you **encode** the unicode (using the utf-8 encoding), and to turn a string to a unicode object you **decode** the string using the respective encoding.

For more details on the concepts I suggest reading [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) (not Python specific).

Comment: this doesn't change anything, unfortunately

Comment: The OP's problem is that he/she is trying to handle decoding, instead of leaving it to ElementTree itself...

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Absolutely, I wrote my answer while on the go, should've looked at the question a bit more carefully. While encoding a bytestring to get unicode is definitely wrong, it wasn't the (real) problem here.

Comment: You saved my life :).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the `parse` function, instead of opening the file... (which BTW would require a `.read()` after it for the `.fromstring()` to work...)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
# etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

The most likely your file is not UTF-8. `è` character can be from some other encoding, `latin-1` for example.

Comment: i made sure that the file is save with utf-8 encoding.

Comment: Tried the encoding 'cp-1250', that didn't work. 'latin-1' did. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Function `open()` does not return a `string`. 
Instead use `open('file.xml').read()`.